# PHP Twitter-like mentions with notifications

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to create a system similar to Twitter for mentioning users and receiving a notification if you are mentioned. There has been a lot of questions asking similar things on here but none have appeared to be conclusive and help me out in any way.

My first trouble is parsing the mention when the status is posted, it works to some extent, but I'm not good with the expressions needed to be used. If I posted a status for example saying "@user1 hello there its @user2", then user1 would parse correctly with the @ being the first character but my user2 displays the space as part of the parsed profile link, here is my preg_replace and expression:

```
$STRING = preg_replace('/(^|\s)(@\w+)/','<a href="profile.php?u=$0">$0</a>', $STRING);
```

I also need to know how to display just the username without the @ in the profile link, the current $0 produces the @ symbol too.

As for notifications, I have a table called alerts with this structure:

id | userid | sentby | message | received

The message field contains the notification message content. I was wondering how I can extract any mentions from my submitted form and check if the username exists and then from there create an alert for the user that they have been mentioned in a post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your first regular expression, you could do something like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@(\w+)/', '$1<a href="">$2</a>', $string);
```

That should get you the username without the initial space or @ sign. Basically, we capture the initial space or beginning of the string into a variable, and print that out in the beginning of the replacement. What you end up with in $2 is *only* what follows the @ sign. You could accomplish this with a lookbehind as well, but I feel that this is simpler.

As for your database structure, maybe something like this would do:

```
messages -
id | user_id | message

mentions -
message_id | user_id
```

For each mention, you insert the user_id into the table for the message. You can choose if you'd like to send your alerts in realtime or wait for a batch process (or potentially - depending on performance requirements - just query for posts with a user mentioned whenever you need to by joining the tables).

Comment: Thanks the regex is perfect, as for the notification, I want to keep it the way I have with my alerts, I just need to know how to extract the mentions when I post the form and insert each of them into the alerts table, thanks.

Comment: Some notes for you. Before saving comment is great to replace usernames with their ids, like <user:id>. It prevents to not working links to users profile when user change his username. 

Then you can simple extract users ids in mentions and replace them to their usernames with this regex preg_match_all('/<user:([0-9])>/', $comment, $users).

Answer (score 3):

I have been thinking about this question for a couple hours and although I am somewhat of a novice, I believe I have a way that extracts the mentions and the alerts and stores them into two unidimensional arrays.

```
    <?php
         //a variable ($string) that I thought might look like what you are describing
         $string='@steve how are you? @tom nice to hear from you. So happy that you joined @joe, cool! @mike sweeet!';
         //regex to pull out the mentions and the messages 
         preg_match_all('/@(\w+)|\s+([(\w+)\s|.|,|!|?]+)/', $string, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
            $mention[$i]= $result[1][$i];
            $message[$i]= $result[2][$i];
         }
         //test to make sure that all mentions are stored
         for ($j = 0; $j< $i; $j++){
            echo $mention[$j],'<br/>';
         }
         //test to make sure that all messages are stored
         for ($k = 0; $k< $j; $k++){
            echo $message[$k],'<br/>';
         }
    ?>
```

The explanation, as provided by Regex Buddy), of the regex that I used: @(\w+)|\s+([(\w+)\s|.|,|!|?]+):

```
Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «@(\w+)»
 Match the character “@” literally «@»
  Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w+)»
  Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
  Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+» 
 Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match) «\s([(\w+)\s|\.|,|!|?]+)»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s+»
 Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([(\w+)\s|\.|,|!|?]+)»
  Match a single character present in the list below «[(\w+)\s|\.|,|!|?]+»
     Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
     The character “(” «(»
     A word character (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»
     One of the characters “+)” «+)»
     A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s»
     The character “|” «|»
     A . character «\.»
     One of the characters “|,!?” «|,|!|?»
```

This will even return words in messages that are off-set by parentheses (e.g. (hello)). You should be able to perform any operation you describe using the variables defined in the arrays. If this is not correct, or you are unable, let me know and I will see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this tutorial to [implement twitter style mention system with PHP, MYSQL and jQuery](https://w3lessons.info/2017/10/20/facebook-style-mention-system-with-php-mysql-jquery/)

You have use regrex match to extract @mentions from the content

Thanks

Comment: Please summarize the content of the link in your answer. External content might go offline or change, making your answer outdated for others that might need help in the future...